# Bitmap memory management on Kindle

Tags: android, bitmap, kindle-fire

I have observed differences of heap impact using the LRUCache on an emulator and on a Kindle Fire HD. On the emulator, adding an image (argb) to the cache seems to cost width * height * 4 bytes (observation made with the ddms heap visualizator tool), on the Kindle Fire HD it seems to be less.
For a reference image of 1280 * 800, it costs approximatively 3.9Mb on the emulator and only some kb on the Kindle.

Can you explain this difference ? Is the image stored in Video RAM or native memory ? Is there some kind of compression for the Bitmap object on Fire OS ?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

After tests, it seems to not be stored in native memory. So I guess it uses VRAM.